# SDP formulation of dual norm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, matrix-norms

I know that the dual norm of a matrix can be formulated as a semidefinite program (SDP), i.e., $\|X\|_{2,*}$ is the solution to the following SDP in $Y$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & Y^T X\\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} I & Y\\ Y^T & I\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0\end{array}$$

If instead of $X$, we have $Z = (I - \phi \phi^T)X$, where  $P_s = \phi \phi ^T$ is an orthogonal projection, how can we reformulate our SDP?

\begin{align}
\max_{Y,\phi}. \quad   Y^TZ \\
s.t. \quad \begin{bmatrix}I & Y\\ Y^T& I \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
Z = (I - \phi \phi^T)X \\
\phi \succ 0
\end{align}

Comment: Is $\phi$ a variable? If so you can't express this as an SDP, because it's not convex.

Comment: Yes, it is. I was hoping there's a work around perhaps with the schur complement lemma. Thank you for your answer, Michael!